# How difficult is it to check if a group element is in a sub group?

Tags: number-theory

I am just curious. We have a group $G$ and its subgroup $H$ with a generator element $h \in H$. How difficult is it to check for $x \in G$ that $x \in \langle h \rangle$? Is there a better way than testing $x \equiv h^1,\ x \equiv h^2,\ x \equiv h^3,\ ...$?

Comment: I guess there is a generic algo that runs in $\sqrt{s}$ time where $s$ is the order of the subgroup, and group specific algos that may be much faster.

Comment: The answer depends upon the group, and potentially upon how group elements are represented.  What group did you have in mind?

Comment: It was just a general question. I didn't have a specific group in my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the group $G$ is finite and cyclic (and hence Abelian), it has exactly one subgroup of order $s$, for each $s$ which divides the order of $G$.

Since any subgroup of a cyclic group is also cyclic and hence Abelian, you might easily implement the operation in $H$ that is the equivalent of modular exponentiation in $Z_n^*$.

If you also already know the order $s$ of $h$, you know that, because of associativity and commutativity, that $(h^s)^t = (h^t)^s = 1$ for any $t$. Hence, checking that $x \in H$ is just a question of checking that $x^s = 1$.

Comment: That may be sufficient, depending on the group.  Just because $x^s = 1$ does not mean that $x$ is in the subgroup you're interested in, there might be a second subgroup of the same size, even if $G$ is Abelian.  Consider the case where $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_s \times Z_s$; that has two subgroups of size $s$; just checking if $x^s=1$ will tell you if it's in one of the subgroups, just not which one.  Now, where we're dealing with multiplicative groups $Z^*_p$, we never get groups like this; however, it can happen in the more general case.